# ¿Como puedo generar en un excel mas de una hoja con la librería SpreadSheetLight en C#?

Tags: c#

La idea es generar un archivo excel con la cantidad que me devuelvo una base de datos, pero en este caso lo estoy probando con un arreglo de datos que llene para realizar la prueba. a partir de ello lo que quiero validar es que si la cantidad de registros supera a la cantidad máxima que permite el excel por hoja (1.048.576) el resto de registros mayores debería de escribirse en otra hoja.
Lo estoy tratando de simular con una arreglo de 30 registros y le estoy colocando un tope de 10 por hoja, pero me da ciertos problemas.
Alguien que me pueda ayudar porfavor.
Por el momento estuve probando así.
Para generar la primera hoja.

```
    List<Ventas> lst = LlenarLista(); //areglo de datos para generar el excel
                int hojas = 0; //numero de hojas
                int registros = 0; //contador de los registros
                int fila = 9; //indica apartir de que fila empezará a escribir los datos.
                if (hojas == 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (i <= 10)
                        {

                            sl.SetCellValue("A" + fila, lst[i].ruc);
                            sl.SetCellValue("B" + fila, lst[i].codigocomercio);
                            sl.SetCellValue("C" + fila, lst[i].producto);
                            sl.SetCellValue("D" + fila, lst[i].moneda);
                            sl.SetCellValue("E" + fila, lst[i].fechaOperacion);
                            sl.SetCellValue("F" + fila, lst[i].tipoOperacion);
                            fila++;
                            registros = i; ;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            hojas = 2;
                            break;

                        }
                    }
                }
```

luego para generar otra hoja.

```
do
            {
                fila = 9;
                sl.AddWorksheet("Sheet" + hojas);
                int total = lst.Count - registros;
                for (int i = registros + 1; i < lst.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (i <= total)
                    {
                        sl.SetCellValue("A" + fila, lst[i].ruc);
                        sl.SetCellValue("B" + fila, lst[i].codigocomercio);
                        sl.SetCellValue("C" + fila, lst[i].producto);
                        sl.SetCellValue("D" + fila, lst[i].moneda);
                        sl.SetCellValue("E" + fila, lst[i].fechaOperacion);
                        sl.SetCellValue("F" + fila, lst[i].tipoOperacion);
                        fila++;
                        registros = i;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        hojas++;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            } while (registros == lst.Count);
```

No se si estaré bien o tienen otro manera de hacerlo mas dinámico.
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: Que no me genera dinamicamente, asi como lo tengo solo es para 2 hojas, pero en el caso de que sean 3 a más hojas ahí tengo el problema. siento que algo me faltaría ahí en el código que estoy tratando de hacer, por eso solicite ayude con la experiencia que puedan tener aquí y me apoyen. Gracias.